# How to manipulate the border of table tag in HTML using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am  making a leader board for a game in HTML. I have decided to use the `z-index:` values in order to place elements on top of a HTML canvas. For the leader board I have decided to use the `<table>`, because it will make the functionality of the leader board easier later on. However, I am trying to make the table look nice, and therefore having trouble with the CSS. I have decided to implement the CSS in the HTML rather than a separate CSS file, because at this point I am just checking if it works. What I am trying to do is have a border all around the cells, or have a vertical line that differentiates between the two headings. Below is my code:

```
<table id = Name&Time
       style=
           "z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            font-family: Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
            width: 332px;
            height: 24px;
            top: 200px;
            left: 460px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
            background-color:#1567ed;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>1:00</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

What other CSS would I need to add to make the cells have a border all around the cells, or make a vertical line of sorts to differentiate between the two headings.

Something along these lines, where the name of the players goes under the name header and the time taken to finish the game goes under the time header.

[image]

Comment: can you add a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added  a screenshot @DaFois

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a minimal example using a table and two colums, you should adapt it to your case.

```css
table {padding:0; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse;}
td div, th div{
    border:solid black 1px;
    border-radius:6px;
    margin: 0 10px
}
tr td:first-child {border-right: black solid 1px}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2"><div>Title</div></th></tr>
<tr><td><div>cell</div></td><td><div>cell</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok, I understand what `border-radius` is doing, but what does `-moz-border-radius` and `first-child` mean?

Comment: `-moz-border-radius` is specific for mozilla (i'm going to remove it now) `:first-child` is the pseudo-element to apply the css rule only to the first `td`

Answer (score 1):

## [Table Borders](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/#post-150493%20media-150493)

If you want rounded corners on the table you'll need to change `border-collapse` to default of `separate` or just remove it all together. After that, you'll be able to apply `border-radius`. The demo is responsive and looks almost mobile worthy. There's a ton of other issues I could address but I think after reviewing this demo and the link above you should your vague problem resolved.

---

### Demo

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 700 calc(16px + 0.5vw)/calc(1.1em + 0.5vw) Georgia;
  margin: .5em;
}

body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rvL6BRK/9LGTz.png) no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 96vw;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}

h1 {
  font-variant:small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 0.5vw;
  font-size: calc(20px + 1.5vw);
  margin: .5em 0
}

h1 b:first-of-type {
 font-size: 1.15em;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 line-height:0.75;
}

h1 b:last-of-type{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height:0.75;
 vertical-align: sub;
}

table {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 60vw;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  padding:0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-right: 3px ridge #fff;
  border-left: 3px ridge #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px ridge #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

thead tr:first-of-type {
  padding: 0;
}

caption {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  padding:0;
  border-top: 3px ridge #fff;
  border-right: 3px ridge #fff;
  border-left: 3px ridge #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
  width: 60vw;
  min-width:320px;
}

td {
font-weight: 400;
}

thead tr:nth-of-type(2) th:first-of-type {
  border-right: 0.5px inset #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px inset #fff;
}

thead tr:nth-of-type(2) th:last-of-type {
  border-left: 0.5px inset #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px inset #fff;
}

tbody tr td:first-of-type {
  border-right: 0.5px inset #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px inset #fff;
}

tbody tr td:last-of-type {
  border-left: 0.5px inset #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px inset #fff;
}

tbody tr:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: 0px none transparent;
}
```

```html
<main>
<header>
<h1><b>N</b>octurnal Neighbor<b>s</b></h1>
</header>
<table>
  <caption>Leader Board</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th colspan='2'></th></tr>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Time</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Player One</td><td>1:00</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should identify the two columns with different ids, then you set the left side border of the column that is in the right side to any value you want, but don't forget to set the width of the right border to 0px for the column that is in the left side, because if you don't, it with be duplicated if it's the same value, and if not, it will be added.

I wish it helps you.